# Como remover projeto Android do SVN?

Tags: android-studio, svn

Comecei a trabalhar com git e desejo remover todos os resquícios do SVN de meu projeto no Android Studio. Não quero mais visualizar os títulos coloridos para arquivos versionados, não versionados e nem o hisorico de commits para que isso não tenha nenhuma interferência quando configurar o git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remova todas as pastas .svn do seu projeto, "recursivamente".

Em linux, você pode usar o seguinte comando:

`find . -iname ".svn" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -r`

Comment: Obrigado, agora sim o Android Studio não reconhece mais o projeto no SVN!